# PHP code returning an unknown column error

Tags: php, mysql

I wonder if any PHP/MySQL experts out there can help me. I have written a PHP code which I am hoping will add new columns to my table in a database. Here is the following code:

```
     <?php

              // All the database connection codes here

      $retro = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['retro']);
      $moon = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['moon']);
      $astronomicalunit = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['astronomicalunit']);

      $sql = "ALTER TABLE Planets
      ADD (COLUMN 'RetrogradePrograde' VARCHAR(45),
      COLUMN 'NumberOfMoons' VARCHAR(45),
      COLUMN 'DistanceFromSun' SMALLINT(5));";

      $sql = "UPDATE Planets
      SET   RetrogradePrograde = '$retro',
      NumberOfMoons = '$moon',
      DistanceFromSun = '$astronomicalunit';";

      // all the mysqli connection failure notification here

      // close mysqli connection

      ?>
```

But when I try to run this program on my browser, I get the message "Error: Unknown column 'RetrogradePrograde' in 'field list'" How can there be an UNKNOWN column when I have just created it? Please help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unexpected T variable in UPDATE table in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215069/unexpected-t-variable-in-update-table-in-mysql)

Comment: you already asked a question with the exact same lines of code, why are you asking another one?

Comment: It's not the same. The problem in that question was a missing semicolon after the first `$sql` assignment. He fixed that, and now he's running into a MySQL error.

Comment: @Barmar: then it will take 3 or 4 more questions to get it finally running :-D

Answer (score 2):

You have the wrong type of quotes around the column names in the `ALTER TABLE` command. They should be backticks, not single quotes. Or you can omit them entirely, since none of your columns are reserved words. ALso, the optional word `COLUMN` should be outside the parentheses.

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE Planets
    ADD COLUMN (
        `RetrogradePrograde` VARCHAR(45),
        `NumberOfMoons` VARCHAR(45),
        `DistanceFromSun` SMALLINT(5));";
```

See the syntax in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the column from the definition. Try this:-

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE Planets
      ADD COLUMN(RetrogradePrograde VARCHAR(45),
      NumberOfMoons VARCHAR(45),
      DistanceFromSun SMALLINT(5));";
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating table or updating them do not use single or double quotes for the columns the will create sql error.Try this

```
<?php

              // All the database connection codes here

      $retro = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['retro']);
      $moon = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['moon']);
      $astronomicalunit = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['astronomicalunit']);

      $sql = "ALTER TABLE Planets
      ADD COLUMN(RetrogradePrograde VARCHAR(45),
      NumberOfMoons VARCHAR(45),
       DistanceFromSun SMALLINT(5))";

      $sql = "UPDATE Planets
      SET   RetrogradePrograde = '$retro',
      NumberOfMoons = '$moon',
      DistanceFromSun = '$astronomicalunit'";

      // all the mysqli connection failure notification here

      // close mysqli connection

      ?>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: exactly i was also looking for the reason and after little search on mysql i got this it's not to hurt you.